# Delete divs using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm working with divs, jquery & PHP. Here is what I have up to now:

http://rabelatos.com/admin/prueba.php

If you click on some of the 2 gray buttons a new div will be added. But I would like to add a new icon to delete divs.

How can I implement this functionality?

This is the code that I have at this moment:

**HTML & PHP:**

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div align="col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <center>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="addProduct">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="addDrink">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="FoodContainer">
            <div class="form-group row" id="Food" style="display:block">
                <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">
                    Food
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="food[]" id="food[]" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Select</option>
                        <?
                        $s1=mysql_query("select * from productos where idCategoria='2'");
                        while($f1=mysql_fetch_array($s1)){
                            $idProduct=$f1["id"];
                            $title=$f1["titulo"];

                            echo "<p class=\"form-control-static\"><option value=\"$idProduct\">$title</option></p>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DrinkContainer">
            <div class="form-group row" id="Drink" style="display:block">
                <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Drink</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drink[]" id="drink[]" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Select</option>
                        <?
                        $s2=mysql_query("select * from productos where idCategoria='1'");
                        while($f2=mysql_fetch_array($s2)){
                            $idProduct1=$f2["id"];
                            $title1=$f2["titulo"];

                            echo "<option value=\"$idProduct1\">$title1</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var $food = $('#Food'), count = 1;
        $('#addProduct').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var idname = 'food' + (++count);
            $food.parent().append($food.clone().attr({id: idname, name: idname}));

        });

        var $drink = $('#Drink'), count = 1;
        $('#addDrink').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var idname = 'drink' + (++count);
            $drink.parent().append($drink.clone().attr({id: idname, name: idname}));
        });

    });
</script>
```

Thanks !

Comment: you can append some element like that but can't delete element in this way, because how jquery should know which div should be delete? you can set delete button for each div.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a delete (an X image) button next to each of the select boxes. As they are distinguished with their IDs (idname) , it can be easily deleted using jQuery. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Yes, I thought to do something like that but my problem is that I don't know how to do it since I'm not an experienced jQuery developer.